# how to fix this problem with start-dfs.sh command

Tags: hadoop, ssh, depth-first-search

I don;t have any firewall specifications.

```
hadoop@Linux:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [hadoop.tecadmin.com]
hadoop.tecadmin.com: ssh: connect to host hadoop.tecadmin.com port 22: Connection timed out
Starting datanodes
localhost: datanode is running as process 4365.  Stop it first and ensure /tmp/hadoop-hadoop-datanode.pid file is empty before retry.
Starting secondary namenodes [Linux]
Linux: secondarynamenode is running as process 4641.  Stop it first and ensure /tmp/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode.pid file is empty before retry



jps command working well :
hadoop@Linux:~$ jps
9952 Jps
4641 SecondaryNameNode
7365 ResourceManager
7501 NodeManager
4365 DataNode
```

I tried this:

```
hadoop@Linux:~$ ssh -vvv hadoop@hadoop.tecadmin.com
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/hadoop/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/hadoop/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "hadoop.tecadmin.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup hadoop.tecadmin.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to hadoop.tecadmin.com [3.130.253.23] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
```

It freezes there.